# How to setup Apache and Laravel in Centos Stream 9

Tags: laravel, apache, firewall

I have a Centos Stream 9 server running Apache 2. I think it is mostly well configured since I never get error messages in my CLI when doing the `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service` command. But I'm getting a 503 error message trying to access my server with the IP or the domain name in a browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

The thing is I have Laravel installed there and I usually run composer to do the updates and I also pull from git. Those commands are ran by my default user `centos:centos`, while my web server is ran by `apache:apache`. I wanted to switch my webserver to the same user because I was getting write permission errors when doing the `composer install` command. The `/storage` and `/bootstrap` directories were owned by the `apache` user.
So, I still don't know if this is something that has to do with my Laravel install, or the server configuration. I was thinking it was a firewall thing, but I'm guessing there must be a way to run my httpd service with my centos user to fix this issue.

Looking into the Error log I found that it was actually getting a message about FastCGI.

```
(13)Permission denied: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
```

Doing some research into the error I understood that it had to do with the configuration of php-fpm

The following is a link to a post that contains good information to solve the problem althought the approved answer is not the correct answer for the problem and I had to dig a little bit into configuring the php-fpm module:
[FPM with apache2 not working (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804659/fpm-with-apache2-not-working-permission-denied)

Lastly, I will share a link to the PHP-FPM installation instructions that also gave me an idea on how to fix it, but not exactly worked for my problem:
[Configure Apache with PHP-FPM](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-and-configure-fastcgi-and-php-fpm-on-centos-8/)

Comment: Please check your apache logs. It'll help us to understand better

Comment: I did some research and updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If possible to you change current configuration?

if yes...
PHP-FPM is able to work using socket file or tcp socket, so you can:

1.Change to TCP configuration (/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf by default)

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
```

2.Change your apache configuration

From:

```
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
```

To:

```
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
```

3.Restart both services.